# Bonferroni Corrections for multiple control groups

Tags: multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

We recently ran a marketing test at work where we are looking at the amount of customers that make a transaction at the store if we do not email them, Email them, email them AND send them a physical mail piece as well.

We also had two groups of customers we were looking at A and B which we aren't interested in comparing to each other, but are interested in how each behaves with respect to its own specific control group.

My question at this point is what the correct way of counting/group the comparisons of this exam for application of Bonferroni or Sidak (or even the Holm- version of those corrections)

We have the following comparisons

```
    A  Email + Direct Mail vs Holdout(A)
    A  Email vs Holdout(A)
    A  Email + Direct Mail vs Email only(A)
    B  Email + Direct Mail vs Holdout(B)
    B  Email vs Holdout(B)
    B  Email + Direct Mail vs Email only(B)
```

My gut instinct is to go with 6 comparisons since that is the number of actual comparisons being made.  However, since there are two separate holdouts I'm not sure if I should correct A and B separately and correct each one for 3 comparisons.

(As an added headache, since my third comparison in A and B is between two different treatments, I'm not entirely positive how to handle them in a multiple comparison problem)

Comment: Are you equating "holdout" with "control"?  (The terms do not ordinarily mean the same thing.)  What exactly do you mean by "looking at A and B"--would those be two different treatments or forms of intervention or values of a binary covariate?

Comment: For the most part, yes.  (For our purposes the holdout is the control, though the Email + DM has an additional control of the email.

Also the A and B are distinct groups of customers, such that A and B are expected to be distinct enough that they deserve their own holdout group for comparisons.  (For example, this could be online customers vs physical store customers, or top performing vs at-risk of loss customers).  We are not interested in comparing A and B directly (i.e. Did A perform better than B, instead we just want to keep A segregated from B for control/holdout purposes.